# Mule 3: How to get the values of "global-property" elements from Java source code

Tags: java, mule

Is there a way to retrieve the values of "global-property" elements in Java code?

```
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core">
  <global-property name="theKey" value="theValue" />
</mule>
```

I'm using Mule 3.2.1.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
MuleContext muleContext = ...
muleContext.getRegistry().get("theKey");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Are you sure that this works for global-properties?  The javadocs say: "Alias method performing the lookup, here to simplify syntax when called from dynamic languages.".  It doesn't mention anything about "global-property" elements.

Comment: Docs, eh? I tested the code works before posting, so yes I'm sure :)

Comment: Alternatively you could use the @Lookup annotation
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Lookup+Annotation

Comment: @VíctorRomero Oh that's cool thanks Victor.  So I can inject the `MuleContext` into a component class just by using the `@Lookup` annotation?  I don't have to implement the `MuleContextAware` interface, right?  That's nice because it's less code the class has to have.

Comment: Yes, you can. But if the only thing you need from the context is the registry, you can just inject registry values 
@Lookup(value = "api.key", optional = true)
private String apiKey;